# Starting something at a certian time and then stopping it

Tags: automation, cron, garrys-mod

I run a Garry's mod server and I want to stop my server at 7AM then start it again. To safely close the server it requires me to type `quit` in the server console. How could I make a script that rules `quit` in the console then starts my `start.sh` file after that is done? I was looking at crontabs but they are confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Garry's mod servers, but in general you can do the following in a cron file:

```
0 7 * * * quit && /path/to/start.sh
```

the first bit ensures that the command is run at 7AM of machine's time every day. You can use [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) as a simple UI that shows what the numbers and * mean on cron scheduling.

I've assumed that `quit` closes the piece of code running on the machine, and doesn't restart or shutdown it down.

Also make sure to use absolute paths when running scripts from cron files.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this run on a screen session? I use the box for stuff like my discord bot as well and I would like to be able to access those as well

Comment: Screen as in this command https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen? Cron runs on the host machine at specific times, screen just creates sessions. No matter how many sessions are active, cron is gonna do what specified system wide, given that the host is up and running. So cron is gonna do what specified, even if you have other screen sessions running. Does that answer your question?